# get average of query result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Ive got query like this:

```
select distinct UserID, Count(UserId) as MyNumber from  dbo.User2User group by UserId
```

now I would like extend this query to get MIN, MAX and AVG of MyNumber

no idea how to get to this value from another select or sth ...

thanks for help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use your own query as a subquery :

```
SELECT MIN(MyNumber) AS minNumber, MAX(MyNumber) AS maxNumber, AVG(myNumber) AS avgNumber
FROM (SELECT UserID, COUNT(UserID) AS MyNumber
      FROM dbo.User2User
      GROUP BY UserID) TMP;
```

Note that the DISTINCT keyword isn't necessary : GROUP BY already selects distinct UserID.

Comment: Dont know why but to make it work I had to Add allias name for that subquery: SELECT MIN(MyNumber) AS minNumber, MAX(MyNumber) AS maxNumber, AVG(myNumber) AS avgNumber
FROM (SELECT UserID, COUNT(UserID) AS MyNumber
      FROM dbo.User2User
      GROUP BY UserID) MyAlias;

Comment: All subqueries must have an alias, regardless of whether or not you use it.